# Payment Gateway CCAvanue with Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, payment-gateway, payment, apex, ccavenue

CCAvenue does not provide integration kit for Salesforce Apex language. They provide Asp.net, Java, NodeJS, iOS, Android, Windows.

How do we encrypt data and make request for CCAvenue payment gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggle we managed to get encrypt and dcrypt data in salesforce apex.

**Here is Encryption:**

/*

This PLAIN_TEXT is your data collected from your apex form. Few values are required and lots of values are optional. Please read document provided by ccavenue.

*/

String PLAIN_TEXT = 'tid=XXXX&merchant_id=XXXX&order_id=XXXX&amount=XX&currency=INR&redirect_url=XXXX&cancel_url=XXXX&language=EN&billing_name=XXXX&billing_address=XXXX&billing_city=XXXX&billing_state=XX&billing_zip=XXXX&billing_country=XXXX&billing_tel=XXXX&billing_email=XXXX&delivery_name=XXXX&delivery_address=XXXX&delivery_city=XXXX&delivery_state=XXXX&delivery_zip=XXXX&delivery_country=XXXX&delivery_tel=XXXX&merchant_param1=XXXX&merchant_param2=XXXX&merchant_param3=XXXX&merchant_param4=XXXX&merchant_param5=XXXX&promo_code=&customer_identifier=&';

//WORKING_KEY is key provided by CCAvenue when you register as Merchant.

Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('WORKING_KEY');

Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', cryptoKey );

Blob data = Blob.valueOf(PLAIN_TEXT);

Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', hash , data);

String encRequest = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedData );

/*Pass this encRequest with access_code to the https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction using visualforce FORM
*/

**Here is Decryption:**

Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('WORKING_KEY');

Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', cryptoKey);

Blob data = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('ENC_RESPONSE'); //Received from ccAvenue response

Blob decryptedText = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', hash, data);

String PLAIN_TEXT = decryptedText.toString();

Comment: CC-Avenue Payment Gateway Response Page return 404 error?
Here is my code :

https://paiza.io/projects/SUiG5qp_wttfcrQn-0Mwew?language=php FYI -> [index.htm -> LineNo : 781 & 782]



After successfully received payment response page return 404 error



The form & CC-Avenue Payment Gateway Request page working good, after customer paid the response page return 404 error.



How can i solve the error?